# How can I change the size of a picture from a square to a circle using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a logo that I need to insert into an html page, that logo is in a square size but I need it to become a circle, how can I do that using CSS?

Answer (score 3):

```
.logo {
    background: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

This should do the job. Set the background url to the one of the logo and height and width accordingly.

Comment: with 100px width/height, 50px radius (half the dimension) should suffice.

Comment: or, just use `border-radius:50%;`, it's easier

Comment: Using percentage for border-radius can lead to the circle becoming an elipse if the height doesn't equal the width. Depending on what you want to do, you either have to use percentage or pixels - the outcome varies. In this case I just wanted to make sure he gets a full circle, but it actually doesn't matter which one you use here.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann if the height doesn't equal the width, it isn't a circle anyway, no matter if you set the `border-radius` with a percentage or not. True, if you are looking to make a rectangle with the left and right side circular, you would need to specify the size in another unit, such as px or em.

Answer (score 2):

Use `border-radius`. A simple example you can see here:

```css
img.logo {
  -webkit-border-radius:50%;
  -moz-border-radius:50%;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
```

Comment: Yeah! better approach!

Answer (score 0):

Use border-radius then set overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

use border and make
border-radius:50%;